# How do I access a variable defined inside my nuxt module from my server middleware API in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have defined a nuxt module in my project that initializes a websocket server ws.js

```
import http from 'http'
import WebSocket from 'ws'
import sessionParser from './session'
 
const map = new Map()
 
function noop() {}
 
function heartbeat() {
  this.isAlive = true
}
 
export default function () {
  this.nuxt.hook('render:before', (renderer) => {
    const server = http.createServer(this.nuxt.renderer.app)
    // overwrite nuxt.server.listen()
    this.nuxt.server.listen = (port, host) =>
      new Promise((resolve) =>
        server.listen(port || 3000, host || 'localhost', resolve)
      )
    // close this server on 'close' event
    this.nuxt.hook('close', () => new Promise(server.close))
 
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true })
 
    server.on('upgrade', function (request, socket, head) {
      console.log('Parsing session from request...')
 
      sessionParser(request, {}, () => {
        // if (!request.session.userId) {
        //   socket.destroy()
        //   return
        // }
 
        console.log('Session is parsed!', request.session.userId)
 
        wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function (ws) {
          wss.emit('connection', ws, request)
        })
      })
    })
 
    wss.on('connection', function (ws, request) {
      const userId = request.session.userId
      map.set(userId, ws)
      ws.isAlive = true
      ws.on('pong', heartbeat)
      ws.on('message', function (message) {
        //
        // Here we can now use session parameters.
        //
        console.log(`Received message ${message} from user ${userId}`)
      })
 
      ws.on('close', function () {
        map.delete(userId)
      })
    })
 
    const interval = setInterval(function ping() {
      wss.clients.forEach(function each(ws) {
        if (ws.isAlive === false) return ws.terminate()
 
        ws.isAlive = false
        ws.ping(noop)
      })
    }, 30000)
 
    wss.on('close', function close() {
      clearInterval(interval)
    })
  })
}
```

- I added this file to my nuxt.config.js inside modules section
- I have an api.js file which gets added to serverMiddleware: ['~/api.js'] and contains express route definition etc
- **I want to access the wss variable from my module inside my api.js file**
- How do I go about it?